# Find average of one field for null values of another field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two text boxes to calculate sum and average. One text box is used to calculate sum of null values in a field for which I use this function:

```
=Sum(IIf(IsNull([field1])=True,1,0))
```

This gives correct answer, but for another text box I need to calculate average of field2 only for records that corresponds to null values of field1. I tried using `DAvg()` function which give back the average of whole field2 which is not what I want. Can anyone please help?

Comment: What is keeping you from replacing `Sum` with `Avg`?

Comment: Avg shall give the average of entire field2 but I want average of field2 only for the corresponding null values of field1 not the whole field2

Comment: Then don't average the whole field, average the same expression you used to sum them:  `=Avg(IIf(IsNull([field1])=True,1,0)) `

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth isn't this worth an answer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It might be, but I don't think it's that simple. Will repost as an answer if it's right.

Comment: Hi Erik, Thanks for helping me out however the =avg() which you mentioned will give average of whole field1 but I want average of field2 ONLY for hose records that are corresponding to null values of field1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a DAvg with a where condition:

```
=DAvg("Field2", "MyTable", "Field1 Is Null")
```

An alternate approach, that is more optimized for aggregate queries, would be the following:

```
Sum(Iif(IsNull(Field1), Field2, 0))/Count(Iif(IsNull(Field1), 1, Null))
```

Since the sum divided by the amount is equal to the average, and Access doesn't count `Null`. Note that this alternate approach might return an incorrect result if there are rows where `Field1` and `Field2` are both `Null`